# Chained dropdown in Django is not storing data to database(Postgresql)

Tags: python, jquery, django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to create a chained drop-down in Django that is on selecting country only those states who belongs to the country should come in the drop-down to select.I have used J-Query for drop-down and is working fine.
But after sending data from form the form data is coming to console as i have print the form values into the console for better understanding, but is not saving the data to the database and form.is_valid is giving False even if data is correct.

Why it is not storing to the database even if the form data s correct

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser,AbstractUser

class Country_Model(models.Model):
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.country

class State(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country_Model,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name



class StudentsRegistrationModel(AbstractUser):
    GENDER = (('F', 'Female',),('M', 'Male',),('O', 'Other',))
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    fathers_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=GENDER,default=None)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country_Model,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    state = models.ForeignKey(State,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone_number = models.CharField(verbose_name="Phone Number",max_length=10)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS=[]
```

form.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from app1.models import StudentsRegistrationModel,State

class Students_Registration_Form(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('first_name','last_name','gender','address','country','state','phone_number','email','password1','password2')
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(Students_Registration_Form,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['country'].empty_label = 'Select'
        self.fields['state'].empty_label = 'Select'
        self.fields['state'].queryset = State.objects.none()
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from app1 import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('home/',views.home,name='home'),
    path('add/',views.insert_student_details,name='add-student'),
    path('ajax/load-cities/',views.load_cities, name='ajax_load_cities'),

]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect 
from  django.contrib import messages 
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from app1.models import StudentsRegistrationModel,Country_Model,State
from app1.form import Students_Registration_Form
def home(request):
    return render(request,'app1/home.html')

def insert_student_details(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = Students_Registration_Form(request.POST)
        first_name = request.POST.get('first_name')
        last_name = request.POST.get('last_name')
        gender = request.POST.get('gender')
        address = request.POST.get('address')
        country = request.POST.get('country')
        state = request.POST.get('state')
        phone_number = request.POST.get('phone_number')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        password1 = request.POST.get('password1')
        print(first_name)
        print(last_name)
        print(gender)
        print(address)
        print(country)
        print(state)
        print(phone_number)
        print(email)
        print(password)
        print(password1)

        print(form.is_valid())
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            print('Record Inserted Successfully')
            messages.success(request,"Thanks for successfull Registration")
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            print('Not stored')
    else:
        form = Students_Registration_Form()

    return render (request,'app1/info.html',{'form':form})


def load_cities(request):
    country_id = request.GET.get('country')
    cities = State.objects.filter(country_id=country_id).order_by('name')
    return render(request, 'app1/city_dropdown_list_options.html', {'cities': cities})
```

base.html

```
 <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>
    Welcome to Recruitment Site
    </h1>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
    </body>
    </html>
```

city_dropdown_list_options.html

```
<option value="">Select</option>
{% for city in cities %}
<option value="{{ city.pk }}">{{ city.name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

home.html

```
     {% extends 'app1/base.html' %}
        {% block content %}
        
        <p>
        I am home page
        </p>
        {% endblock content %}
```

info.html

```
 {% extends 'app1/base.html' %}
    {% block content %}
    <p>I am  Info Page</p>
      <form action="" method="post" id="personForm" data-cities-url="{% url 'ajax_load_cities' %}" novalidate>
            {% csrf_token %}
            <table>
              {{ form.as_table }}
             </table>
            <button type="submit">Register</button>
          </form>
          <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
          
          <script>
            $("#id_country").change(function () {
              var url = $("#personForm").attr("data-cities-url");  // get the url of the `load_cities` view
              var countryId = $(this).val();  // get the selected country ID from the HTML input
          
              $.ajax({                       // initialize an AJAX request
                url: url,                    // set the url of the request (= localhost:8000/add/ajax/load-cities/)
                data: {
                  'country': countryId       // add the country id to the GET parameters
                },
                success: function (data) {   // `data` is the return of the `load_cities` view function
                  $("#id_state").html(data);  // replace the contents of the city input with the data that came from the server
                }
              });
          
            });
          
    
            
          </script>
    {% endblock %}
```

Output at Console:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
April 01, 2021 - 10:35:03
Django version 2.2, using settings 'custom_pro.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[01/Apr/2021 10:35:19] "GET /ajax/load-cities/?country=230 HTTP/1.1" 200 4815
[01/Apr/2021 10:35:22] "GET /ajax/load-cities/?country=231 HTTP/1.1" 200 2460
harsh
singh
M
Dallas
231
3970
8547896654
h@gmail.com
asdf@1234
False
Not stored
[01/Apr/2021 10:35:36] "POST /add/ HTTP/1.1" 200 13714
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your forms `__init__` method you write:

```
self.fields['state'].queryset = State.objects.none()
```

That's fine initially but the fields queryset is also used to validate whether the choice selected by the user is correct. So this causes no choice to be valid in this case. You should handle the case where `country` is already selected or the form is just updating an instance:

```py
class Students_Registration_Form(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('first_name','last_name','gender','address','country','state','phone_number','email','password1','password2')
    
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(Students_Registration_Form,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['country'].empty_label = 'Select'
        self.fields['state'].empty_label = 'Select'
        self.fields['state'].queryset = State.objects.none()
        if self.instance.pk:
            # If updating an instance
            self.fields['state'].queryset = self.instance.country.state_set.order_by('name')
        if 'country' in self.data:
            # If this is a submitted form
            try:
                country_id = int(self.data.get('country'))
                self.fields['state'].queryset = State.objects.filter(country_id=country_id).order_by('name')
            except (ValueError, TypeError):
                pass
```